# Check if a parent iFrame has jQuery already loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, authentication, widget

I'm trying to create a login widget in an iframe that can be used on a clients website. This iframe will be using jQuery, but I first wont to be able to check if the parent document has jQuery loaded, if not, load it.

I've tried several different techniques but none seem to wont to work, or decide to load the jQuery library twice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This code block is within the page loaded inside the iframe, which refuses to co-operate.

```
<script>

var jQOutput = false;

function initjQuery() { 

if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined'){     
    if (!jQOutput){         
        jQOutput = true;

        var jScript = document.createElement('script');
        jScript.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        jScript.setAttribute("src", "js/libs/jquery/jquery-min.js");
    }
    setTimeout("initjQuery()", 50);
} else {
    $(function() {
        $("#email").css({"background":"red"});
        //visual aid to see if jQuery is loaded.
    });
} 
}
</script>
```

I just want to check and see if the parent to the iframe has loaded jQuery, and if not, load it myself, as I'll be using it to perform several tasks needed to complete the login proceedure.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, I dont think what you want to archive is posible because of same origin policy (Cross domain access via JavaScript) - look it op on Google... https://www.google.com/search?q=same+origin+policy

Comment: @AndreasAL, you mean achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Entented comment:

> I dont think what you want to archive is posible because of same origin policy (Cross domain access via JavaScript) - look it op on Google... http://google.com/search?q=same+origin+policy

---

If you on the other hand dont violate the same origin policy you can archive what you want using something like this:

```
var parent = window.parent; // This refers to parent's window object

if ( parent && parent.jQuery ) { // Check to see if parent and parent.jQuery is truly
    window.jQuery = parent.jQuery;
    window.$ = parent.jQuery;
}
else {
    // load jQuery here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I've tried what you suggested but it still doesn't work. Think it just isn't possible.

Comment: @AndrewBurns As what I can understand you are trying to access a parent from an iFrame from another domain. This is **not** posible.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript code of your widget has to be divided into two parts. One of them would be loaded on a client's site. It would have permissions to access the DOM of the site: load jQuery if needed, create an iframe, etc. (Be especially careful with global variables there! Try not to use them at all since they can conflict with the code of the site.) Note that this part wouldn't have access to the DOM of the iframe. That's why you need the second part, which would be loaded inside of the iframe. You can use cross-domain techniques for the parts to exchange messages with each other. I'd advise you to check out the [easyXDM library](http://easyxdm.net).